# MeteorJS click event issue when using meta viewport tag on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, meteor

I've stumbled across this strange Meteor JS behaviour when using the following meta tag in the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

When tapping anywhere on the body in iOS Safari some kind of click/touch event is triggered. It's clearly visible because it creates and outline/highlight on the body just like it would for a normal link when it's clicked.

For a demo open this link on your iPhone:
http://metaviewportissue.meteor.com and click anywhere on the body.

Code is here:
https://github.com/st3phan/meteorviewportissue

When I remove the meta viewport tag the click/touch event on the body is gone.

Does someone know what's going on here and maybe how to get rid of this strange behaviour?

Versions:
Meteor 1.0
Safari 8.1